# Best practice with using targets in iOS project

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am developing an iOS application and I have two projects (*two clients*). I have created a second targets by duplicating the first one, my question how I can test if I am in `targetX` / `targetY` ? What are the best practice when developing an iOS applications with multiple targets.

Comment: What do you mean "if I am in target X" ? and why do you want to know?

Comment: for example in my code : if (target = 1) NSLog(@"target1") else ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know if this is best practice, but one way to do this is to add an *Other C Flag* in the target's build settings (see image). For example:

Target A:

```
-DAPP_ZENDER=1
```

Target B:

```
-DAPP_ZENDER=2
```

And then in code you can check for this define:

```
- (NSInteger)appZender {
#if APP_ZENDER == 1
    return 1;
#elif APP_ZENDER == 2
    return 2;
#endif
}
```

[image: The 'Build Settings' option]

Comment: This, or using Preprocessor Macros and check them using `#ifdef` or similar.

Comment: @Hyperbole That also works, but would require him to either juggle target specific headers and/or defines or remember that different targets require some commenting/uncommenting of his preprocessor macros. Setting them in the target build settings is a 'set once and forget' solution, which is nice.

Comment: Preprocessor Macros can be set in the build settings in the same was as Other C Flags, no juggling required.

Comment: If it can be done in build settings, then this is also a valid method. Any advantages over using Other C Flags?

Answer (score 0):

Checking for the target in your code doesn't seem like the best solution for your situation, whatever that may be.  I’d look into creating two or more subclasses to deal with the differences in logic, or using more than one localized string file, if that would suffice.